# ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB using video format yuv to rgb

Tags: android, renderscript

I was searching for a video yuv converts to rgb and I found this to android ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB renderscript, Is there someone implements this to their android project?

Comment: If you have a specific question, you need to ask it.  See the [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help page.

Comment: I was asking who has already used this to the video frame conversion yuv to rgb

Comment: Yes, I see that.  But this is not the forum for that type of question.  Stackoverflow is for help answering specific technical questions.